# Error caused by ApplicationUser that inherits IdentityUser class when updating the database with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to build a one-to-many relationship between my ApplicationUser and Transactions model. ApplicationUser extends IdentityUser with the following additional property:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ICollection<Transactions> Transactions { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is my Transactions model:

```
public class Transactions
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PhoneId { get; set; }
        public Phone Phone { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public Customers Customer { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public TransactionType TransactionType { get; set; }
        public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
        public decimal TransactionAmount { get; set; }
    }
```

When I add a new migration, in addition to creating new tables and everything I also get altering of these columns in the database:

```
            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "Name",
                table: "AspNetUserTokens",
                type: "nvarchar(128)",
                maxLength: 128,
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(string),
                oldType: "nvarchar(450)");

            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "LoginProvider",
                table: "AspNetUserTokens",
                type: "nvarchar(128)",
                maxLength: 128,
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(string),
                oldType: "nvarchar(450)");

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
                name: "Discriminator",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                type: "nvarchar(max)",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: "");

            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "ProviderKey",
                table: "AspNetUserLogins",
                type: "nvarchar(128)",
                maxLength: 128,
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(string),
                oldType: "nvarchar(450)");

            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "LoginProvider",
                table: "AspNetUserLogins",
                type: "nvarchar(128)",
                maxLength: 128,
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(string),
                oldType: "nvarchar(450)");
```

And when I try to update my database I get this error:

> Error Number:5074,State:1,Class:16
> The object 'PK_AspNetUserTokens' is dependent on column 'Name'.
> ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Name failed because one or more objects access this column.

I ran it by ChatGPT and it suggested the following:

> You need to first drop the primary key constraint on the 'AspNetUserTokens' table before attempting to update the 'Name' column. Here are the steps you can follow to do this: ...

But I'm interested is there any other less risky way of fixing this issue since I'm not that experienced with database management.

Comment: try adding `virtual` to the ApplicationUser prop in the Transaction class like this `public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }` because this is a virtual entity and not a class property when you need all the data about the user you can make an `Include()` statement for the user and you will get all the data about the user who created that Transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by dropping my database completly and built it from scratch. I was able to do this since I just started the development of the app.